Calculating Torsion for elementary collapses
I refer to M.Cohen for my definitions.
I am trying to understand the notion of "torsion" defined by
$$ 
\tau(C) = \prod_{i = 0}^m[b_i b_{i-1}/ c_i]^{{-1}^{(i+1)}}
$$
In particular, if I were to consider $C, C'$ to be within the same acyclic chain complex, then I should get
$$
\tau(C') = \tau(C) \prod_{i = 0}^m[ b_{i}/ c_i]^{{-1}^{(i+1)}}
$$
I was wondering if someone can provide a canonical example for calculating the torsion of an elementary collapse?
I am looking for something like a tetrahedron collapsing a vertex which leaves a (flat) triangle. It should be the case that the torsion is $0$ though I am not clear how to derive that answer?
I am also interested in calculating Whitehead torsion, though I am not clear precisely how different it is from this definition?
Any resources etc. are also welcome.
